# Incompatible color definition when using tikz with svgraybox (from svmono)

Tags: tikz-pgf, sv-classes

With the following code I get the warning "Incompatible color definition". When I remove the package tikz, the warning disappears. But I need this package. Can I avoid the warning?
I have to use the class svmono from
https://www.springer.com/engineering?SGWID=0-175-6-1381428-0

Thanks!

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}            % Instead of \usepackage{amsmath} in order to avoid Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}    % Instead of mathptmx, since with mathptmx Warning: there are no bold math fonts 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{svgraybox}
Hello.
\end{svgraybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) since `svmono` is not a standard class included with LaTeX, it might be an idea to provide a link to where you got `svmono` from.

Comment: My guess is that xcolor is being loaded twice by different packages that you are using but with different colour options. Try adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` before your `\documentclass` command. I don't have svmono.cls installed so I can't test...

Comment: @daleif Of course you're right. I provided a link (by editing the post).

Comment: @Andrew Sounds good. But your suggestion did not help. (Messages are exactly the same).

Comment: erh, that is not the error I get. Please find the first error in your editor, it complaines that `svgraybox` does not exist. So from where do you have that `svgraybox` should be something that is supported?

Comment: The `svgraybox` command comes from  `\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}` and does not produce a problem itself.

Comment: There is no `svgraybox` listed anywhere in the data I downloaded from the link you provided, I took the data in `http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/72921/application/zip/svmono.zip`

Comment: Also please remember the `@`name when you are addressing someone, then they will be informed that you wrote something.

Comment: The discussion below the original question asks what `svmono` is. `svmono` is a documentclass of the Springer publishing house for writing monographs and textbooks. It can be downloaded, for example, from https://www.springer.com/engineering?SGWID=0-175-6-1381428-0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I could resolve it. The solution was replacing in svmono.cls itself the command \Requirepackage{color} by \Requirepackage{xcolor}.